# One checkbox checked at a time - not radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

First, before you recommend radio buttons, I want to use checkboxes because they can be unchecked. I have 2 custom checkboxes #c1 & #c2; I want one open at a time (so if c1 was open, clicking c2 will uncheck c1); and I want both to be able to be unchecked. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Here's what I've tried:`

```js
let c1 = document.getElementById('c1');
let c2 = document.getElementById('c2');

function oneAtATime() {
  if (c1.checked) {
    c2.checked = false;
  } else if (c2.checked) {
    c1.checked = false;
  }
}
c1.addEventListener('change', oneAtATime);
c2.addEventListener('change', oneAtATime);
```

```html
<input id="c1" type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="check">
<label for="c1">
        <h2>example</h2>
    </label>
<input id="c1" type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="check">
<label for="c1">
        <h2>example</h2>
    </label>
```

Comment: You could make your life easier by, when a checkbox is clicked, unchecking all checkboxes, then re-checking the one that was clicked.

Comment: IDs **must** be unique

Comment: Are you really limited to 2 checkboxes? Or are there actually more than 2?

Comment: Sorry about the typo! My id's are indeed unique. My checkboxes here are actually the top of CSS accordions - my design only needs 2.

Answer (score 1):

For jQuery >= 1.6

```
$('.check').prop('checked', true);
$('.check').prop('checked', false);
```

For jQuery < 1.6:

```
$('.check').attr('checked', true);
$('.check').attr('checked', false);
```

Snippet:

```js
$('.check').click(function(){
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('.check').prop('checked', false);
    $(this).prop('checked', true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="c1" type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="check">
<label for="c1">
        <h2>example</h2>
    </label>
<input id="c2" type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="check">
<label for="c2">
        <h2>example</h2>
    </label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just check if the item being clicked has been turned on or off, like:

```js
let c1 = document.getElementById('c1');
let c2 = document.getElementById('c2');

function oneAtATime() {
if (this.checked){ // Item clicked has been turned on
    if (this == c1){
        c2.checked = false;
    } else {
        c1.checked = false;
    }
}
}
c1.addEventListener('change', oneAtATime);
c2.addEventListener('change', oneAtATime);
```

```html
<input id="c1" type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="check">
<label for="c1">
        <h2>example</h2>
    </label>
<input id="c2" type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="check">
<label for="c2">
        <h2>example</h2>
    </label>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `this` in the event listener to refer to the element that was clicked on. You only need to uncheck the other box when you're checking the current box.

```js
let c1 = document.getElementById('c1');
let c2 = document.getElementById('c2');

function oneAtATime() {
  if (this.checked) {
    let other = this == c1 ? c2 : c1;
    other.checked = false;
  }
}
c1.addEventListener('change', oneAtATime);
c2.addEventListener('change', oneAtATime);
```

```html
<input id="c1" type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="check">
<label for="c1">
        <h2>example</h2>
    </label>
<input id="c2" type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="check">
<label for="c2">
        <h2>example</h2>
    </label>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
c1.onclick=()=>{
 if(c2.checked) c2.checked=false;
}

c2.onclick=()=>{
 if(c1.checked) c1.checked=false;
}
```

```html
<input id="c1" type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="check">
<label for="c1"><h2>example</h2></label>
<input id="c2" type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="check">
<label for="c2"><h2>example</h2></label>
```

First you should change id to c2 to the second section, and make sure the `for` attribute to c2 too, then check out this easy vanilla JS function, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

this will work as you requested with the 2 checkbox tick enabled by default ,

it will work with any jquery version as well .

if you clicked in any checkbox the other one will be unticked .

hope this helps you :)

on your html page this is the code :

```
<input id="c1" type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="check" onchange="unloadc1()">
<label for="c1">
<h2>example</h2>
</label>
<input id="c2" type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="check" onchange="unloadc2()">
<label for="c1">
<h2>example</h2>
</label>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<Script>


function unloadc2() { 
document.getElementById("c1").checked = false;
document.getElementById("c2").checked = true;

}

function unloadc1() { 


document.getElementById("c2").checked = false;
document.getElementById("c1")
```

```html
    <input id="c1" type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="check" onchange="unloadc1()">
    <label for="c1">
    <h2>example</h2>
    </label>
    <input id="c2" type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="check" onchange="unloadc2()">
    <label for="c1">
    <h2>example</h2>
    </label>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <Script>


    function unloadc2() { 
    document.getElementById("c1").checked = true;
    document.getElementById("c2").checked = false;

    }

    function unloadc1() { 


    document.getElementById("c2").checked = true;
    document.getElementById("c1").checked = false;

    }

    $(function() {
    document.getElementById("c1").checked = true;
    document.getElementById("c2").checked = true;
    });
    </script>
```